# Adding prefex and suffix to all elements of a list of string in CloudFormation

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I am trying to write a generic CFN template that takes a list of bucket names as a parameter and then append adds "arn:aws:s3:::" before and "/*" after each element. Aim is to say white list certain number of buckets all together.

For example:

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "This template creates a managed policy for s3 bucket whitelisting (ReadOnly) in AWS",
    "Parameters" : {
        "ManagedPolicyName" : {
          "Type" : "String",
          "Description" : "Enter a name for the policy being created"
        },
        "RoleAttachement" : {
            "Type" : "CommaDelimitedList",
            "Description" : "Enter a comma delimited list of ROLE NAMES the policy needs to be attached to"
        },
        "WhitelistBuckets" : {
            "Type" : "CommaDelimitedList",
            "Description" : "Enter a comma delimited list of BUCKET NAMES the policy needs to whitelist"
          }
    },    
    "Resources": {
       "ManagedPolicy": {
          "Type": "AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy",
          "Properties": {
                "PolicyDocument": {
                                 "Version": "2012-10-17",
                                 "Statement": [
                                    {
                                        "sid": "ConsoleAccess",
                                        "Effect": "Allow",
                                        "Action": [
                                          "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                                          "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
                                        ],
                                        "Resource": "*"
                                    },
                                    {    
                                        "Effect": "Allow",
                                        "Action": [
                                            "s3:List*",
                                            "s3:Get*"
                                            ],
                                        "Resource": [
                                          <LIST MANIPULATION HERE>
          
                                        ]
                                    }
                                    ]
                                },
                "ManagedPolicyName": {"Ref": "ManagedPolicyName"},
                "Roles": {"Ref": "RoleAttachement"}
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

What I would like is some form of manipulation script that adds in buckets like

```
"arn:aws:s3:::bucket1",
"arn:aws:s3:::bucket2",
"arn:aws:s3:::bucket1/*",
"arn:aws:s3:::bucket2/*"
```

At this point I am not sure if this is possible in CFN. Can anyone please guide? Thanks in advance

Comment: As you wrote, its not possible.

Comment: There's an open issue in the roadmap for this: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/1864